# how thymeleaf can find the template location?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

i'm getting a warn when i start my spring boot app, is the following:

```
2023-02-16T13:26:47.508-05:00 WARN 23919
--- [ restartedMain] DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration
Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Thymeleaf configuration, or set spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=false)
```

but my application.properties is the following:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
```

everything seems to be normal, but I keep getting that error

my resources directory is the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVqMk.png)

does anyone know what's going on? the answers I've looked for don't fit my weird situation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `src/main/resources/templates` is [the default directory](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-template-directory) for Thymeleaf templates, so I guess you need to remove property `spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/` letting Spring to use the default one.

Comment: i did it, but still it doesn't work, in fact when i try to create a html file in the templates directory in spring web tools i can't, like it don't work as a template directory

Comment: oh, the html file is for another reason, i just realize now

Comment: You can put the file there manually in IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in a Junit5 test, and had to push my files my files `src/test/resources/templates` and it fixed the issue. My configuration looked the same, but I later changed using:

```java
templateResolver.setPrefix(templatesDirectory); // Set the folder where your templates are located
```